# Does the removal of a few edges remove all paths to a node?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I'm making a game engine for a board game called [Blockade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockade_(board_game)) and right now I'm trying to generate all legal moves in a position. The rules aren't exactly the same as the actual game and they don't really matter. The gist is: the board is a matrix and you move a pawn and place a wall every move.

In short, I have to find **whether or not a valid path exists from every pawn to every goal after every potential legal move** (imagine a pawn doesn't move and a wall is just placed), to rule out illegal moves. Or rather, if I simplify it to a subproblem, *whether or not the removal of a few edges (placing a wall) removes all paths to a node*.

Brute-forcing it would take *O(k*n*m)*, where *n* and *m* are the board dimensions and *k* is the number of potential legal moves. Searching for a path (worst case; traversing most of the board) is very expensive, but I'm thinking with dynamic programming or some other idea/algorithm it can be done faster since the position is the same the wall placement just changes, or rather, in graph terms, the graph is the same which edges are removed is just changed. Any sort of optimization is welcome.

### Edit:

To elaborate on the wall (blockade). A wall is two squares wide/tall (depending on whether it's horizontal or vertical) therefore **it will usually remove at least four edges**, eg:

p | r 
q | t

In this 2x2 matrix, placing a wall in the middle (as shown) will remove jumping from and to: 
*p and t, q and r, p and r, and q and t*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize ahead of time if I don't fully understand your question as it is asked; there seems to be some tacit contextual knowledge you are hinting at in your question with respect to knowledge about how the blockade game works (which I am completely unfamiliar with.)

However, based on a quick scan on wikipedia about the rules of the game, and from what I gather from your question, my understanding is that you are effectively asking how to ensure that a move is **legal**. Based on what I understand, an illegal move is a wall/blockade placement that would make it impossible for any pawn to reach its goal state.

In this case, I believe a workable solution that would be fairly efficient would be as follows.

Define a path tree of a pawn to be a (possibly but not necessarily shortest) path tree from the pawn to each reachable position. The idea is, you want to maintain a path tree for every pawn so that it can be updated efficiently with every blockade placement. What is described in the previous sentence can be accomplished by observing and implementing the following:

- when a blockade is placed it removes 2 edges from the graph, which can sever up to (at most) two edges in all your existing path trees
- each pawn's path tree can be efficiently recomputed after edges are severed using the "adoption" algorithm of the Boykov-Komolgrov maxflow algorithm.
- once every pawns path tree is recomputed efficiently, simply check that each pawn can still access its goal state, if not mark the move as illegal
- repeat for each possible move (reseting graphs as needed during the search)

Here are resources on the adoption algorithm that is critical to doing what is described efficiently:

- open-source implementation as part of the BK-maxflow: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.html
- implementation by authors as part of BK-maxflow: [https://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html](https://pub.ist.ac.at/%7Evnk/software.html)
- detailed description of adoption (stage) algorithm of BK maxflow algorithm: section 3.2.3 of [https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yboykov/Papers/pami04.pdf](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eyboykov/Papers/pami04.pdf)

Note reading the description of the adopton algorithm included in the last
bullet point above would be most critical to understanding how to adopt
orphaned portions of your path-tree efficiently.

In terms of efficiency of this approach, I believe on average you should expect on average `O(1)` operations for each adopted edge, meaning this approach should take about `O(k)` time to compute where `k` is the number of board states which you wish to compute for.

Note, the pawn path tree should actually be a reverse directed tree rooted at the goal nodes, which will allow the computation to be done for all legal pawn placements given a blockade configuration.

Comment: If there is any contextual knowledge it is entirely my fault for not elaborating on it, the game is very archaic. Placing a blockade can remove around half a dozen edges (4 usually, 2 from the diagonal squares, since the blockade is 2 squares wide/tall, and two vertically/horizontally across the blockade) depending on the position. I didn't read the described algorithm in detail, I will later tonight, but hopefully, this information doesn't change the problem and solution too much. I will update the info about the blockades in my question. Thank you for the elaborate answer

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

**To check if there's a path from A to B after ever** 
Every move removes a node from the graph/grid. So what we want to know is if there are critical nodes on the path from A to B (single points that could be blocked to break the path. This is a classic [flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem). For this application you want to set the vertex capacity to 1 and push 2 units of flow (basically just to verify that there are at least 2 paths). If there are 2 paths, no one block can disconnect you from the destination. You can optimize it a bit by using an implicit graph, but if you're new to this maybe create the graph to visualize it better. This should be O(N*M), the size of your grid.

**Optimizations**
Since this is a game, you know that the setup doesn't change dramatically from one step to another. So, you can keep track of the two paths. If the blocade is not placed on any of the paths, you can ignore it. You already have 2 paths to destination.
If the block does land on one of the paths, cancel only that path and then look for another (reusing the one you already have).

You can also speed up the pawn movement. This can be a bit trick, but what you want is to move the source. I'm assuming the pawn moves only a few cells at a time, maybe instead of finding completely new paths, you can simply adjust them to connect to the new position, speeding up the update.

Comment: If I understood it right, if I find two distinct paths removing any one edge(node) will still leave a path, which makes sense, but placing a blockade can remove multiple edges (since pawns can travel diagonally, edge cases, blockades are 2 squares long, etc...). Does your solution still apply, and don't we just end up brute-forcing it whenever the two paths end up getting blocked, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know the game. Thanks for the clarification, it actually makes it easier. We create an artifical edge representing the blocade. The for connections you mention in the example, they will go through the artificial edge. You will have two options for moving left (going through the blocade extending above or the one extending below). You only need capacities over the artificial edges we just added.

Comment: By construction you can't place a blocade to block both paths. So at most you end up having to look for another path. If you don't find it, then there is a position where you can place a blocade to block the pawn completely. If you want to find the place look on the wiki for the minimum cut, that will give you the edge(now this corresponds to a blockade) that if removed block all paths.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think I'll be able to combine both of the solutions you and Idog gave in an optimal way.